# How to show items in a php array greater than zero

Tags: php

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around arrays, so far nothing I've read seems to make sense to me so I apologize in advance if this is a silly question? I have built this:

```
<?php $inv_array = compact("a_inventory", "b_inventory", "c_inventory", "d_inventory");  ?>
            <?php
            foreach($inv_array as $key => $value) {
            echo "$key: $value<br />";
            }
```

which is displaying the different inventory levels and locations perfectly.What I would like to do next is say if it is in the array and greater than zero echo "In Stock" else "Out of Stock"

Thnaks in advance for any help offered!

Comment: Where is the stock stored?

Comment: `if it is in the array` -- *what* in *which* array? And what's the `compact()` function doing?

Comment: The stock is stored at any combination of warehouses. For example, there could be 3 on hand at a_inventory and 2 on hand at d_inventory and 0 at the other locations.

Comment: Stored in the snippet of code you have given.

Comment: Amal, I am not sure what the compact() function does, it was something I found at another forum. I apologize, but I am not a programmer, just trying to fix an issue we are having that we don't have resources for?

Comment: compact is a PHP function http://us1.php.net/compact

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you've described below

```
$instock = false;
foreach($inv_array as $value) {
    if($value > 0) {
        $instock = true;
    }
}
echo  ($instock) ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock";
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for, but it outputs a message for each location. I am looking for a way to check each location for a quantity greater than zero and if there is at least one then say In Stock, however if every location is zero, then Out of Stock if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are using `compact()` leads me to believe you are building a multi-dimensional array (where **a_inventory**, **b_inventory**... are all their own arrays with products and stock values), one `foreach` will most likely not be enough. If you have something like this:

```
$a_inventory[0]['product'] = 'product1';
$a_inventory[0]['stock'] = '2';

$a_inventory[1]['product'] = 'product2';
$a_inventory[1]['stock'] = '0';

..and so on

$inv_array = compact("a_inventory", "b_inventory", "c_inventory", "d_inventory");

foreach($inv_array as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $newKey => $newValue){
        if(($newKey == 'stock') && ($newValue > 0)){
             echo $newKey . " : " . $newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not sure how to make each inventory location it's own array. Basically the stock quantities are passed to a field as an attribute and I am pulling them via: <?php $inventory_a = $_product->getInventoryA(); ?>